# Generating tree with long data

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, treeview

I am working on spring boot and angular js application created using jhipster, in this I have generate tree view like

- Root

  - Child_1
  - Child_2

    - Sub_Child_2_1

      - Sub_Child_2_1_1
  - Child_3

    - Sub_Child_3_1
  - Child_4
  - Child_5

    - Sub_Child_5_1
    - Sub_Child_5_2
    - Sub_Child_5_3
      ......
      ......
      ......

At initial level, I will load child with two levels i.e. root -> Child_1..2..3..
Later sub_child will be loaded as per requirement. Depth of tree is not fixed, it may vary. The data is very large. So I can not load all at initial level.

I want tree to be expanded and collapse functionality.

**EDIT :** I have tried abn tree, but it caused issue mentioned at : [abn tree fail to show correctly when reach to level 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41178369/abn-tree-fail-to-show-correctly-when-reach-to-level-9)

What will be best to solution to create tree in my jhipster application so that it can edited easily?

Answer (score 0):

You can create here custom directives to generate tree structure on your data.

Comment: Thanks, Can you show me example and also I have updated the question.

Comment: Can you please try below link- 


http://angular-js.in/angular-tree-control/

http://alexsuleap.github.io/ 

http://angularscript.com/demo/creating-a-tree-structure-with-angularjs-and-json-data-angularjs-tree/

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use templates :

Tree JSON :

```
$scope.tree = [
    {
        name: "Child 1"
    },
    {
        name: "Child 2",
        subs: [
            {
                name: "Subchild 2 1",
                subs: [
                    {
                        name: "Subchild 2 1 1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

HTML :

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in childs">
            {{ item.name }}
            <div ng-include="'myTemplate'" 
                 ng-if="item.subs"
                 ng-init="childs = item.subs"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>

<div ng-include="'myTemplate'" ng-init="childs = tree"></div>
```