# abn tree fail to show correctly when reach to level 9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, tree

I have to generate tree view, so I have created tree using abn-tree in my spring boot jhipster application.

As tree will be generated at runtime and level(depth) of tree is not fixed. I have tried depth 8 with abn-tree, but as it go to level 9, its view scattered. Node added after shifted towards right side and whole tree view not display correct.

[image: Tree View on level 9]

I need tree structure like Windows Registry Editor as :

[image: Tree View like Windows Registry Editor]

You can check the issue at : http://embed.plnkr.co/Nxi2Nl/ by putting data in app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['angularBootstrapNavTree']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  var treedata_geography = [{
    label: 'North America',
    children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
      children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
      children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
      children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
     children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
     children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
     children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
      children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
      children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
      children: [{
      label: 'Canada',
      children: ['Toronto', 'Vancouver']
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
    }, {
      label: 'USA',
      children: ['New York', 'Los Angeles']
    }, {
      label: 'Mexico',
      children: ['Mexico City', 'Guadalajara']
    }]
  }, {
    label: 'South America',
    children: [{
      label: 'Venezuela',
      children: ['Caracas', 'Maracaibo']
    }, {
      label: 'Brazil',
      children: ['Sao Paulo', 'Rio de Janeiro']
    }, {
      label: 'Argentina',
      children: ['Buenos Aires', 'Cordoba']
    }]
  }];
  $scope.my_data = treedata_geography;

});
```

How can I resolve the issue. I have tried various css changes. If this will not solve the issue then what will best to generate tree on runtime with expand collapse feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the .css file (which you haven't included in your question, but you should put the relevant code in there).

You'll see that only 9 levels of indentation are defined for the list items, so after nine levels, they fall back to the left margin. The last level in the CSS is:

```
ul.nav.nav-list.abn-tree .level-9 .indented {
  position: relative;
  left: 160px;
}
```

Just add more levels as desired, and indent each 20 pixels more:

```
ul.nav.nav-list.abn-tree .level-10 .indented {
  position: relative;
  left: 180px;
}

ul.nav.nav-list.abn-tree .level-11 .indented {
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
}
```

etc. etc.